# Java Thread Safety Analysis on compile time

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, clang

I've programmed for years on C++, and [Clang's Thread Safety Annotations](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html) really helps me to find bugs related on the data races. It doesn't have a runtime overheads and it is used widely IMO.

Also I need to code using Java and I would like to use such powerful static analysis on JAVA. Are any recommendations?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [softwarerecs.se], though I recommend reading their rules first just in case.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is something like this for java. In C++ any data race is Undefined Behavior (if we are talking about C/C++11 memory model). In Java we do not have such a thing and before Java 9 we have only "happens before" which essentially corresponds to sequential-consistency memory ordering. Speaking with wording of C/C++ Standards data races in java have unspecified behavior, not undefined.